# Trying to write javascript to output Delivery cost for my website but the code won't display the value

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I have so far.  Someone posted it for people to use.  It calculates distance well but when I try to calculate my delivery cost, it wont give me an error but it also won't output the value.  The "$?" stays the same.  I don't have a lot of experience coding and I've tried a number of things.  I'm at a loss here.  Please help!

```
<font face="cookie"><script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>

<!-- Browser key 1 -->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?    file=api&v=2&key=AIzaSyA9kMASRkOAbPFdzd4u5o_F0JyXKieOSQk"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Initialize location vars 
var location1;
var location2;
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('test');
  initialize();

  //Grab the address values from the form on submit, and then run the maps code
   $('#map-form').submit(function(event) {
      //Also, stop the form from actually submitting
      event.preventDefault();
      address1 = $('#address1').val();
      address2 = $('#address2').val();
      //Run it, baby!
      showLocation();
  });
});
var geocoder, location1, location2;
function initialize() {
  //Create new object of the google maps api
  geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
}
function showLocation() {
  geocoder.getLocations(address1, function (response) {
    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
    {
      alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode address 1");
    }
    else
    {
      location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
      geocoder.getLocations(address2, function (response) {
        if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
        {
          alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode address 2");
        }
        else
        {
          location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
          calculateDistance();
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
function calculateDistance()
{
  try
  {
    var glatlng1 = new GLatLng(location1.lat, location1.lon);
    var glatlng2 = new GLatLng(location2.lat, location2.lon);
    var miledistance = glatlng1.distanceFrom(glatlng2, 3959).toFixed(1);
    var kmdistance = (miledistance * 1.609344).toFixed(1);
    //Write the value wherever you want!
    $('#mile_distance').html(miledistance);
  }
  catch (error)
  {
    alert(error);
  }
}
price = $('#price').val();
delivery = $('#delivery').val();
var miles = mile_distance - 25;
if (miles<0)
{
 miles = 0;
}
var C = (miles * .575);
$('#price').val(C.toFixed(2));
var delivery_cost = 10;
var D = (delivery_cost + price);
$('#delivery').val(D.toFixed(2));
</script>

<form id="map-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Address 1" id="address1" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Address 2" id="address2" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p>The distance is: <span id="mile_distance">?</span> miles</p>

<p>Your delivery cost is: $<span id="delivery">?</span> </p>
</font>
```

Comment: My issue is with the delivery calculations as the bottom just above the form.

Comment: I'm really lost in your question, what exactly do you want?

Comment: #delivery is id of span tag, and span doesn't have val() attribute... use text() instead.

Comment: I want the last line of code that outputs the delivery cost to actually output a value.  When the program is used, it outputs the distance for the customer to see but the delivery cost remains unchanged.  There is no value output for delivery cost at all but I'm not getting any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is not a part of any function and, therefore, will be executed immediately after it's loaded, even before your GUI fully appears on the screen.

```
price = $('#price').val();
delivery = $('#delivery').val();
var miles = mile_distance - 25;
if (miles < 0) {
  miles = 0;
}
var C = (miles * .575);
$('#price').val(C.toFixed(2));
var delivery_cost = 10;
var D = (delivery_cost + price);
$('#delivery').val(D.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: jeez  Thank you.  I've been starring at it for so long i didn't see it. haha